# A bug about sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]([id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MyNumericColumn] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,[insert_time] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__MyTable__insert___0F975522]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([id] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
exec sp_executesql N'insert into MyTable (  MyNumericColumn, insert_time ) values ( @P0, getdate())，( @P1, getdate())',N'@P0 decimal(38,1),@P1 decimal(38,2)',10.0,0.99
exec sp_executesql N'insert into MyTable (  MyNumericColumn, insert_time ) values ( @P0, getdate())，( @P1, getdate())，( @P2, getdate()) ',N'@P0 decimal(38,2),@P1 decimal(38,1),@P2 decimal(38,3)',0.99,10.00,0.999
select * from [MyTable];
exec sp_executesql N'insert into MyTable (  MyNumericColumn, insert_time ) values( @P0, getdate()),( @P1, getdate()), ( @P2, getdate())',N'@P0 decimal(38,2),@P1 decimal(38,2),@P2 decimal(38,3)',0.99,10.00,0.999
select * from [MyTable];
```

while @P0 decimal(38,2),@P1 decimal(38,1),@P2 decimal(38,3) why all data are decimal(38,1)..

Comment: You're likely the victim of data type inference at the end of whatever client you're using to generate these statements. For example, all ADO.NET clients will attempt to infer the type of parameters based on the parameter value alone, not on the statement. A value like `0.999` will be inferred as `decimal(38, 3)` because that's considered a "safe" precision, regardless of whether this ends up making sense in the query. In the case of `decimal` especially this can lead to unintuitive or incorrect results, which is why you should take care to specify scale and precision explicitly.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, perhaps [AddWithValue](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) is the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rounding behavior is expected and not related to `sp_executesql`. Row constructors behave similarly to `UNION` and `UNION ALL` in combining expressions of different types. The rules for combining decimal types of differing precision and scale are described in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql).

Consider this repro using a `UNION ALL SELECT` query with local variables:

```
DECLARE
     @P0 decimal(38,1) = 10.0
    ,@P1 decimal(38,2) = 0.99
SELECT @P0 
UNION ALL
SELECT @P1;
```

Result:

```
+------------------+
| 10.0             |
| 1.0              |
+------------------+
```

Executing the query with `sp_describe_first_reesult_set` shows the resultant type is `decimal(38,1)` instead of the `decimal(38,2)` as one might expect, resulting in the 0.99 value to be rounded to 1.00. This is done to avoid truncating the integral portion when where larger values are specified.

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'
DECLARE
     @P0 decimal(38,1) = 10.0
    ,@P1 decimal(38,2) = 0.99
SELECT @P0 
UNION ALL
SELECT @P1;
';
```

If we reduce the scale to 37, the result type is `decimal(38,2)` and these values are not rounded. However, it is a best practice to declare parameter types to match that of the target table with the understanding that values with a greater precision will be rounded:

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert into MyTable (  MyNumericColumn, insert_time ) values ( @P0, getdate()), ( @P1, getdate())',N'@P0 decimal(38,2),@P1 decimal(38,2)',10.0,0.99
exec sp_executesql N'insert into MyTable (  MyNumericColumn, insert_time ) values ( @P0, getdate()), ( @P1, getdate()), ( @P2, getdate()) ',N'@P0 decimal(38,2),@P1 decimal(38,2),@P2 decimal(38,2)',0.99,10.00,0.999
select * from [MyTable];
exec sp_executesql N'insert into MyTable (  MyNumericColumn, insert_time ) values( @P0, getdate()),( @P1, getdate()), ( @P2, getdate())',N'@P0 decimal(38,2),@P1 decimal(38,2),@P2 decimal(38,2)',0.99,10.00,0.999
select * from [MyTable];
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @key, glad it helped. I fixed the doc link in my answer.